# In UserControl how to set ControlToValidate Property of Validator to a control in parent page textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, comparevalidator

I am getting this error below

** Unable to find control id 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvExpense$ctl03$lblIncTotalAmt' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'cmpAmountAdj'**

Here CompareValidator "cmpAmountAdj" is inside gridviewrow
*strGridControlToValidate* is Id of gridview of parent page
*strControlToValidate* is Id of textbox inside footer of parent gridview

```
 ((CompareValidator)e.Row.FindControl("cmpAmountAdj"))
.ControlToValidate = ((Label)(GridView)this.Parent
.FindControl(strGridControlToValidate)).FooterRow
.FindControl(strControlToValidate)).UniqueID;
```

Please Suggest...

Comment: Why is the compare-validator in a row and the control it should compare in the footer? Btw, where is this code located, in `RowDataBound`? Why is the compare-validator not in the same `NamingContainer`? Why do you put all in a single line, your code is nearly unreadable.

Comment: Yes code is located in RowDataBound of gridview in an user control

Comment: where is your usercontrol placed on the page. can you provide html source of the page.

Comment: Any specific reason for not using validator alongwith control to be validated

Comment: @AmitRanjan My cmpAmountAdj.ControlToCompare Control is inside UserControl so it can be directly assigned, but cmpAmountAdj.ControlToValidate Control is on Parent page.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli Providing source is not possible.

Comment: Ok then according to your code your gridview and usercontrol needs to be inside same container.